# Ionic run changing files back from changes

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

My ionic app was running fine yesterday.
This morning when I ran `ionic run android --live-reload` the file constant.js was "rolled back" to it's initial state, before I made my changes.

Here is what constant.js looks like:

```
angular.module('whatever')

.constant("DB_NAME", "whatever.db")

// .constant("ENV", "production")
.constant("ENV", "dev")

.constant("CONFIG", {
  "production": {
    "url": "<production url>"
  },
  "dev": {
    "url": "http://<my ip>:3000"
  }
})
```

The file SHOULD be as pointed above. But every time I use the command previously mentioned, the commented ENV change and the IP in dev url too (the changes I made before run).
I already tried to remove and add platform android, no luck.

Comment: Where is located this file ? If it is in platforms it is normal. You need do edit file in www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was changing the inner constant.js, no the main one that generated the others. That's why, when generated, the variables where changing back.